# Pyo in Python: name 'Server' not defined

Tags: python, audio, pyo

I recently installed Pyo, and I entered Python 3.6 and typed

```
from pyo import *
s = Server().boot()
s.start()
sf  = SfPlayer("C:\Users\myname\Downloads\wot.mp3", speed=1, loop=True).out()
```

but I get

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\pyo.py", line 1, in from pyo import * File "C:\Python27\pyo.py", line 2, in s = Server().boot() NameError: name 'Server' is not defined

how do I play the audio file?

Answer (score 1):

Your own script is called "pyo.py", so when you do `from pyo import *` it just looks at your file, not the pyo library. Rename your file.