# Pyo in Python; name 'Server' not defined

Tags: python, audio, pyo

I use python 3.6, and I am trying to play an audio file with pyo, but when I try to run it, I get this message;

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\pyotest.py", line 1, in 
>       from pyo import *
>     File "C:\Python27\pyo.py", line 2, in 
>   NameError: name 'Server' is not defined

My code:

```
from pyo import *

s = Server().boot()
s.start()
sf  = SfPlayer("C:\Users\*****\Music\sound.mp3", speed=1, loop=True).out()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyo in Python: name 'Server' not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893964/pyo-in-python-name-server-not-defined)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have created the file `C:\Python27\pyo.py`. So instead of the actual pyo module getting imported, your file gets imported.

Rename the file `C:\Python27\pyo.py` and any pyc file (`C:\Python27\pyo.pyc`) associated with it and try again

Comment: (or rename it instead of deleting it)

Comment: I was testing it earlier and I made a file name pyo, but then I deleted it but it still won't work

Comment: @Emyeetko. Well, your traceback still refers to the file `C:\Python27\pyo.py`. So it looks like that file still exists. Can you check again there is not file named `pyo.py` or `pyo.pyc` in `C:\Python27\`

Comment: @Sunitha there is a file named 'pyo' and it's type is a compiled python file, and I tried deleting it but when I ran my code, it said 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\pyotest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyo import *
ImportError: No module named pyo'

Comment: @Emyeetko. Well. In that case, it looks like pyo module is not installed, or installed on some non-standard location.

Comment: Do you suggest I install it again?

Comment: @Emyeetko. If you have already installed, check if your PYTHONPATH is set correctly. I dont use windows, so I cannot recommend how PYTHONPATH should look like